# Что не так с этим LocalTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Проект Spring + Thymeleaf
Вот описание в сущности:

```
@Entity
public class CarEntity {
...
    @Column(name = "time_oot", nullable = false)
    private LocalTime timeOut;
}
```

Читаем время в формате LocalTime с HTML формы.
Пока был вывод без секунд, все работало.
Т.е. форма ввода была такого вида:

```html
<label for="inputime">Время</label>
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputime" placeholder="Задайте время" max="0:50:00" min="0:00:01" value="00:00" th:field="*{timeOut}" required>
```

Но мне не нужны часы на форме, а только минуты и секунды, я добавил на форму секунды:

```html
<label for="inputime">Время</label>
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputime" placeholder="Задайте время" max="0:50:00" min="0:00:01" value="00:00:00" step="1" th:field="*{timeOut}" required>
```

И теперь стала вылетать ошибка:

```
Field error in object 'CarEntity' on field 'timeOut': rejected value [00:12:25]; 
codes 
[typeMismatch.CarEntity.timeOut,typeMismatch.timeOut,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalTime,typeMismatch]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [CarEntity.timeOut,timeOut]; 
arguments []; default message [timeOut]]; 
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalTime' for property 'timeOut'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] 
to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.time.LocalTime] for value '00:12:25'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [00:12:25]]]
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Очевидно, что проблема в том, какой шаблон строки времени ждёт Спринг, чтобы преобразовать строку в дату. Я не знаю, где этот шаблон задаётся. Но думаю, с помощью какой-нибудь аннотации.

Comment: Я знаю только эту:
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "hh:mm:ss")
Но она не помогает. Spring все равно не может сконвертировать

Comment: Я вас понимаю. Но с Thymeleaf я не работал и подсказать не могу. Как раз сейчас у всех данные из морды в бэк по json летят и там @JsonFormat и другие соответствующие аннотации работают. Попробуйте задать вопрос на английском в международной версии стека. Что тут ещё посоветуешь((